# How to read username at the restlet back end code using api-manager?

Tags: restlet, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 api-manager to provide secure access to my restlet uris'.

At the resouce class which extends ServerResource class i need to access the username and store it in db for auditing purpose.

I followed below link for the same

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT

But not sure how to access the username at my resource class.
Can anybody help me for the same.

thank you.
~Shyam

Comment: If I understand well, I don't know how WS02 works really, there is a header which contains a value Base64-encoded. You can check the list of transmitted headers using the Response#getHeaders method (in a server resource: getResponse().getHeaders() ). If you want to Base64-decode the header's value: use the method org.restlet.engine.util.Base64.decode)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Thierry Boileau your information helped to extract the header from the restlet but to decipher the token i followed the below links

http://lalajisureshika.blogspot.in/2013/06/passing-end-user-details-from-client-to.html